# Merge notifications with OneSignal

Tags: ionic-framework, onesignal

Using Ionic and OneSignal.

I am developing a messaging service in my app which sends push notifications when a new message is received. Ok so far.

But, I would like to merge notifications if they exceed a certain number, to avoid spamming the user with to much notifications.

Let's say if someone answer to one of my message with 3 different messages and that my app is in background, I would like the following to happen:

1. receive 1 notification
2. receive 1 other distinct notification
3. display only one notification which merge the previous two + a new one

Someone know, if possible and how?

Answer (score 1):

I have just implemented something similar. You can look at the following documentation link
[stacked notification](https://documentation.onesignal.com/v3.0/docs/android-customizations#section-notification-stacking)

I just set the `android_group` parameter in all of my one signal api call and send a string key on every notification message.

```
{
    app_id = "xxxxxxxxxxxx"; // one signal app id
    headings = "One Signal Title Test";
    content = "The demo test message";
    android_group = "demo-application";
    included_segments = "Active Users"; // to send notification to all active users
}
```

[use postman to test](https://documentation.onesignal.com/v3.0/docs/using-postman)

Answer (score 0):

There's couple of parameters that you can set to group messages.

on `Android` you can use `android_group` witch accept a `string` and based on docs:

> Notifications with the same group will be stacked together using Android's [Notification Grouping](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/android-customizations#section-notification-grouping) feature.

And on `iOS` you can use `thread_id` witch also accept a `string`:

> This parameter is supported in iOS 12 and above. It allows you to group related notifications together. If two notifications have the same thread-id, they will both be added to the same group.

There are couple more parameters that might be useful that you can check on [**Grouping & Collapsing OneSignal Docs**](https://documentation.onesignal.com/reference#section-grouping-collapsing)